# Can I use the same content page with two different master pages?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, master-pages

I have an asp.net content page which is used inside of a master page (with header, menu and some links). I would like to reuse it in a different context without the master page (to not display the header and menu there), or with an empty master page if this is somehow possible. I don't want to violate DRY principle by taking the whole page and creating a standalone clone of it for obvious reasons. Is this somehow possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can set the master page dynamically in the content pages Page_PreInit method:

```
private void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MasterPageFile = "MyMasterPage.master"
}
```

Set up some logic to dynamically choose which master page filename to pass in, and you are now sharing one content page with many master pages.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing! Then there's no need to convert existing pages to a control.

Answer (score 4):

How about wrapping-up the shared content in a [user control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx)?

> [A user control is a kind of composite
>   control that works much like an
>   ASP.NET Web page—you can add existing
>   Web server controls and markup to a
>   user control, and define properties
>   and methods for the control. You can
>   then embed them in ASP.NET Web pages,
>   where they act as a unit.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx)

Comment: Sounds reasonable, I'll probably go this way, thanks. The only problem is that I have to transform the already existing page to a control, but hopefully that's not too much work..